# Is "prima facie case" only used in the context of criminal law?

Tags: legal-terms, prima-facie

Is "prima facie case" only used in the context of criminal law? Or can it be used in administrative and/or civil law?

Answer (score 4):

The concept of prima facie is common also in civil proceedings (and, impliedly, administrative ones).

See the results from [this query](http://www.leagle.com/leaglesearch?all=defamation&exact=prima%20facie), most of which are civil cases. For instance, [this memorandum opinion](https://www.leagle.com/decision/intxco20191105369) begins by acknowledging that the plaintiff-appellees "*have met their burden of establishing a prima facie case for defamation*".

In theory, the purpose of prima facie elements is to establish "high-level" uniformity as to what items a plaintiff or prosecutor, as the case may be, will need to prove in order to prevail in a case. That uniformity is necessary for --and consistent with-- the so-called "equal protection of the laws". From a standpoint of equal protection, there is no reason  why a case being criminal vs. civil should make a difference regarding the applicability of the concept of *prima facie* elements.

Comment: As an example of an administrative law situation, the concept of "prima facie" argument is used in patent law in ex parte procedures between an applicant and a USPTO patent examiner.